# How to Use Regex to Match Multi-line HTML

Tags: python, regex, regex-group, python-re

With the following two HTML examples

```
<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">
    <a href="/en-us/designers/jean-marie-massaud">Jean-Marie Massaud</a>
    (2021)
</div>
```

```
<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">
    <span>R&amp;D Poliform</span>
</div>
```

I want to extract the designer's names; `Jean-Marie Massaud` and `R&amp;D Poliform`.

I tried the following regex:

```
re.compile(
    '<a href="/en-us/designers/.*?">(.*?)</a>'
).findall(html)[0]
```

But it cannot extract the name in `<span>` tags from the 2nd example.

Additionally, I also want multi-line matching for `<div>` tags to take `class` into consideration. In this case,how the regex should be like?

Problem solved version 1.0:

I used:

```
designer = re.compile('<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">[\s\S]*?<[^>]+>([\s\S]*?)</[^>]+>[\s\S]*?.*?[\s\S]</div>').findall(html)[0]
```

It can help me print out the designer name now. However, there is another problem.

I found that there is another type of HTML, where  is empty, like this:

```
<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">


</div>
```

In this case, using the solution I talked about above will not print an empty string/list of string. Rather, it will print out next tag's information.

For example, in this case, the HTML part is:

```
<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">

                    
</div>
<p class="wow fadeInUp" itemprop="description">Cover, design R&amp;D Poliform, with its discrete elegance and variety of finishes, is the perfect completion of Senzafine collection that is enriched with an element that perfectly combines aesthetic and functionality.</p>
```

^where the div tag is empty, and my solution above will print out the p tag after the div tag rather than an empty string. This is the output, it is the p tag after the div tag.

```
                <p class="wow fadeInUp" itemprop="description">Cover, design R&amp;D Poliform, with its discrete elegance and variety of finishes, is the perfect completion of Senzafine collection that is enriched with an element that perfectly combines aesthetic and functionality.
```

How to use regex so that it can include an empty tag as well?

Thanks

Comment: Both? Where is another HTML? And, why don't you use [`Beautiful Soup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: <div class="designer wow fadeInUp">
    <a href="/en-us/designers/jean-marie-massaud">Jean-Marie Massaud</a>
    (2021)
</div>  ---- This is from one HTML

<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">
    <span>R&amp;D Poliform</span>
</div>  ---- This is from another HTML.

I don't use Beautiful Soup is because I know how to use re and requests, and they are more customised. Beautiful Soup framework will limit my development.

Comment: You need to find `R&amp;D Poliform` from the `<span>` element?

Comment: For the first HTML: I need to find the text/string "Jean-Marie Massaud". For the second HTML: I need to find "R&amp;D Poliform" or "R&D Poliform". Yes.

Comment: They are from two HTMLs, but I want to combine them into one Regex expression.

Answer (score 2):

How about to use more general regular expression to make it work on both `<a>` and `<span>` tags?

```
reo = re.compile('<[^>]+>(.*?)</[^>]+>')
```

#### The Questioner's Solution

For multi-line matching:

```
reo = re.compile(
    '<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">'  '[\s\S]*?'
        '<[^>]+>([\s\S]*?)</[^>]+>'        '[\s\S]*?'
    '</div>'
)
```

Comment: Let me try try.

Comment: So it has to be under the <div> with class: "designer wow fadeInUp", do you think there is any function to search the children of a tag...? Would that be useful?

Comment: @GloriaChen Beautiful Soup, exactly. People will also recommend for this problem.

Comment: Nice. Hey thanks! I used this:
 "designer": re.compile('<div class="designer wow fadeInUp">[\s\S]*?<[^>]+>([\s\S]*?)</[^>]+>[\s\S]*?</div>').findall(html)[0],
Problem solved!

Comment: Ah... I did not understand that you wanted to match `<div>` tag as well.

Comment: @GloriaChen I made an edit for your solution. Please consider to accept it if you don't mind. :D

Comment: wowwww Thank you! You are so cool! Let me read read.

Comment: Or you can answer to yourself. I edited your question to emphasize multi-line matching. I think your solution is great. If you make your own answer, I will edit mine again back.

Comment: Thank you, it works and printed a list of string with one element. However, I have another question again.